# Fill fullcalendar draggable events area from a database

Tags: jquery, asp.net, database

I have a question about how to fill draggable events area from a data base and how to save users choices, using Asp and Ado.. will you help me please :)
this is the instance I'm working on : [this one](http://arshaw.com/js/fullcalendar-1.5.2/demos/external-dragging.html)